# MySQL query much slower when using join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database and one query which I'm trying to optimize as well as I can.

I'm not familiar with indexes, so I do not know which indexes I should create. At the moment I do not have any indexes and my query is too slow, I think. In fact, using `join` has made this all much slower. I believed that it would make this faster, but not. I do not understand why this is much slower now.

Any suggestions for indexes? Is there anything else I could make better to make my query faster?

```
            SELECT ka_ki.kierrosnumero AS kierrosnumero
            , ka_ki.kierroskoodi AS kierroskoodi
            , ka_ki_ot.ottelunumero AS ottelunumero
            , ka_ki.haviajien_sijat_tekstina AS haviajien_sijat_tekstina
            , ka_ki.voittajien_puolelta_cupiin AS voittajien_puolelta_cupiin
            , ka_ki.haviajien_puolelta_cupiin AS haviajien_puolelta_cupiin
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_a_ja_b_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_a_ja_b_kaaviokoodi 
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_a_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_a_kaaviokoodi
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_b_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_b_kaaviokoodi
            , ki_ka_ot.id AS ki_ka_ot_id
            , ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_monesko_peli_ottelussa
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_pelipaikka_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_pelimuoto_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_voittopisteet
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_aikataulutus
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_alkamisaika
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_loppumisaika
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_tiimiilmo_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_tiimiilmo_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_peluri1ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_peluri2ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri1ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri2ilm_id
            , ki_il.pari_joukkue_nimi_txt AS peli_paikka_b_pari_joukkue_nimi_txt
            , ki_il.sijoitusnumero_syotetty AS peli_paikka_b_sijoitusnumero_syotetty
            , ki_il.sijoitusnumero_arvottu AS peli_paikka_b_sijoitusnumero_arvottu
            , ka_il.pelaaja_oma_nimi_txt AS peli_paikka_b_peluri1_oma_nimi_txt
            FROM ki_ka_ot
                    JOIN ki_il ON ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_tiimiilmo_id = ki_il.id
                    JOIN ka_il ON ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri1ilm_id = ka_il.id
                    JOIN ki_ka ON ki_ka.id = ki_ka_ot.kaavio_id
                    JOIN ka_ki_ot ON 
                            ki_ka.kaaviopohja_id = ka_ki_ot.kaaviopohja_id
                            AND ka_ki_ot.id = ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id
                    JOIN kaa ON ka_ki_ot.kaaviopohja_id = kaa.id
                    JOIN ka_ki ON ka_ki_ot.kierros_id = ka_ki.id
            WHERE ki_ka_ot.kaavio_id = 107
            ORDER BY ka_ki_ot.ottelunumero ASC
```

**Update**

Instead of using `join`, I could use `FROM ki_ka_ot, ki_il, ka_il, ki_ka, ka_ki_ot, kaa, ka_ki` and add several `AND` conditions to `WHERE` section. The result of the query would be 100% same, but it would be faster. Should I do it?

```
            SELECT ka_ki.kierrosnumero AS kierrosnumero
            , ka_ki.kierroskoodi AS kierroskoodi
            , ka_ki_ot.ottelunumero AS ottelunumero
            , ka_ki.haviajien_sijat_tekstina AS haviajien_sijat_tekstina
            , ka_ki.voittajien_puolelta_cupiin AS voittajien_puolelta_cupiin
            , ka_ki.haviajien_puolelta_cupiin AS haviajien_puolelta_cupiin
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_a_ja_b_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_a_ja_b_kaaviokoodi 
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_a_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_a_kaaviokoodi
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_b_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_b_kaaviokoodi
            , ki_ka_ot.id AS ki_ka_ot_id
            , ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_monesko_peli_ottelussa
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_pelipaikka_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_pelimuoto_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_voittopisteet
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_aikataulutus
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_alkamisaika
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_loppumisaika
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_tiimiilmo_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_tiimiilmo_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_peluri1ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_peluri2ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri1ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri2ilm_id
            , ki_il.pari_joukkue_nimi_txt AS peli_paikka_b_pari_joukkue_nimi_txt
            , ki_il.sijoitusnumero_syotetty AS peli_paikka_b_sijoitusnumero_syotetty
            , ki_il.sijoitusnumero_arvottu AS peli_paikka_b_sijoitusnumero_arvottu
            , ka_il.pelaaja_oma_nimi_txt AS peli_paikka_b_peluri1_oma_nimi_txt
            FROM ki_ka_ot
            , ki_il
            , ka_il
            , kaa
            , ka_ki
            , ka_ki_ot
            , ki_ka
            WHERE ki_ka_ot.kaavio_id = 107
            AND ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_tiimiilmo_id = ki_il.id
            AND ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri1ilm_id = ka_il.id
            AND ki_ka.id = ki_ka_ot.kaavio_id
            AND ki_ka.kaaviopohja_id = ka_ki_ot.kaaviopohja_id
            AND ka_ki_ot.kaaviopohja_id = kaa.id 
            AND ka_ki_ot.kierros_id = ka_ki.id
            AND ka_ki_ot.id = ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id
            ORDER BY ka_ki_ot.ottelunumero ASC
```

**Update 2**

Now I have modified my original query which uses `join`. I think it works better and faster, but maybe there is something to fix.

```
            SELECT ka_ki.kierrosnumero AS kierrosnumero
            , ka_ki.kierroskoodi AS kierroskoodi
            , ka_ki_ot.ottelunumero AS ottelunumero
            , ka_ki.haviajien_sijat_tekstina AS haviajien_sijat_tekstina
            , ka_ki.voittajien_puolelta_cupiin AS voittajien_puolelta_cupiin
            , ka_ki.haviajien_puolelta_cupiin AS haviajien_puolelta_cupiin
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_a_ja_b_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_a_ja_b_kaaviokoodi 
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_a_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_a_kaaviokoodi
            , ka_ki_ot.paikka_b_kaaviokoodi AS paikka_b_kaaviokoodi
            , ki_ka_ot.id AS ki_ka_ot_id
            , ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_monesko_peli_ottelussa
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_pelipaikka_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_pelimuoto_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_voittopisteet
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_aikataulutus
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_alkamisaika
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_ajankohta_loppumisaika
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_tiimiilmo_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_tiimiilmo_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_peluri1ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_a_peluri2ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri1ilm_id
            , ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri2ilm_id
            , ki_il.pari_joukkue_nimi_txt AS peli_paikka_b_pari_joukkue_nimi_txt
            , ki_il.sijoitusnumero_syotetty AS peli_paikka_b_sijoitusnumero_syotetty
            , ki_il.sijoitusnumero_arvottu AS peli_paikka_b_sijoitusnumero_arvottu
            , ka_il.pelaaja_oma_nimi_txt AS peli_paikka_b_peluri1_oma_nimi_txt
            FROM ki_ka_ot
                    JOIN ki_il ON ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_tiimiilmo_id = ki_il.id
                    JOIN ka_il ON ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_peluri1ilm_id = ka_il.id
                    JOIN ki_ka ON ki_ka.id = ki_ka_ot.kaavio_id
                    JOIN ka_ki_ot ON 
                            ki_ka.kaaviopohja_id = ka_ki_ot.kaaviopohja_id
/* AND ka_ki_ot.id = ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id */
                    JOIN kaa ON ka_ki_ot.kaaviopohja_id = kaa.id
                    JOIN ka_ki ON ka_ki_ot.kierros_id = ka_ki.id
            WHERE ki_ka_ot.kaavio_id = 107
AND ka_ki_ot.id = ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id /* this was moved here */
            ORDER BY ka_ki_ot.ottelunumero ASC
```

Comment: You have no indexes: Adding indexes usually helps

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Yes, I see. My query is so wide that I do not know which indexes I should create.

Comment: The indexes should be created on the values you join on. The others are (most of the time) irrelevant.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Do you mean `ki_ka_ot.peli_paikka_b_tiimiilmo_id`, `ki_il.id` and all other ones which are mentioned with `join`?

Comment: Yes, that should help a bit: No guarantees that it will be great, but indexes are pretty much required for any join performance

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen OK, thanks, I wll give a try. Btw, would you take all joins away or would you use them if this was your query?

Comment: If you want that result, I would run the query with all the joins. If it is really slow, I would analyze and see if it can be optimized by splitting the query, maybe save it to some handy reusable tables, and work with those to get to the end result.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I have updated my opening message and added my query without `join`. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` is a high cost operation that though the optimizer attempts to perform efficiently it cannot without some context of your data. I cannot suggest specific indexes you should make since I too have no context of your data, but you should attempt to index in a way that impacts any operations you wish to perform. So if you have a `JOIN` that joins on column A, you'd want to index on A so the optimizer can efficiently perform that `JOIN`.

Comment: Do you recommend me to take joins away or use them?

Comment: If you need to use the joins, use them, if not, take them away. I'm assuming you need the joins in order to get the data you're after, if not then you'd need to explain why you're using them.

Comment: I could use `FROM ki_ka_ot, ki_il, ka_il, ki_ka, ka_ki_ot, kaa, ka_ki` and add several `AND` conditions to `WHERE` section. The result of the query would be 100% same, but it would be faster. Should I do it?

Comment: Comma notation and `JOIN` notation should be equivalent in every way except visually (ie the optimizer interprets both the same). So if you experience performance changes I'd imagine you're not translating between the notations correctly.

Comment: What do you mean when saying "translating between the notations"?

Comment: How you are writing the query with commas and how you are writing the query with joins is not the same. You may be seeing the same output, but it is highly unlikely they're doing the same thing since the optimizer would write the same expression to actually run on if they were. Meaning they'd perform equivalently. I'd imagine you aren't making the same conditions with your `=` as you are with your `on`, which would effect performance.

Comment: Please take a look at my opening post. I have added my query which does not using `join`. Maybe you can see what is the reason why this is much slower with `join`.

Comment: I would imagine the "JOIN ka_ki_ot ON 
                            ki_ka.kaaviopohja_id = ka_ki_ot.kaaviopohja_id
                            AND ka_ki_ot.id = ki_ka_ot.kaaviopaikka_id" is being read as two joins to the optimizer, since it involves three tables instead of just two. If that's the case the two queries are not equal. You can check equivalency of statements with `EXPLAIN` and `ANALYZE` which will give you a better idea of what the optimizer is actually seeing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I believe you are right. I cannot use `EXPLAIN` or `ANALYZE`. Anyway, I added update 2 to my opening message.